# How do I change my email address in Call of Duty: Elite?

Tags: call-of-duty-elite

I entered the email address wrong and now it won't verify and complains every time I log in

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to http://www.callofduty.com/elite and create a new account. Follow all the steps, then at the end link your Xbox Live or PSN account to your newly-created Elite account. Your old Elite account will no longer be associated. Log out and log in of Xbox Live or PSN on your console, and you're gold.

Comment: If you managed to solve the problem yourself, you should mark this as the solution.